# Unexpected compile error when dealing with vector of unique_ptr<pure_virtual_class> inside std::map

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, stdmap, pure-virtual

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void doIt() = 0;

public:
  int base = 1;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
  Derived(int x) : derived(x) { base = x; }
  void doIt() override { printf("hello from derived class. %d, %d\n", derived, base); }
public:
  int derived = 2;
};

class Storage {
public:
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>> cache;
  void add_to_cache(std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr) {
    cache["row"].back().push_back(std::move(ptr));
  }
  void add_new_cacheLine() {
    cache.emplace("row", std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>{}); // Case I: compile ok.
/*
  std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>> emptyCacheLine{};
  cache.insert("row", emptyCacheLine); // Case II: compile error
*/
  }

  Storage() { 
    cache["row"] = {};
  }
};

int main()
{
  Storage storage;
  storage.add_to_cache(std::make_unique<Derived>(3));
  for (auto& s : storage.cache["row"].back()) {
    s->doIt();
  }
}
```

Here is my example code, when compile it with MSVC with Case II, I get:

```
Error C2280 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

The full build logs here:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(677,47): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\memory(3317,5): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>::unique_ptr'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\memory(3317,5): message : 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(1777,35): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>,
1>            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,
1>            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(1831,17): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Uninitialized_backout_al<std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>::_Emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>&>(std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> &)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\vector(2072,36): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *std::_Uninitialized_copy<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>*,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>*,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>(_InIt,_Se,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *,_Alloc &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *,
1>            _Se=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\vector(684,9): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>::_Construct_n<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>*const &,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>*const &>(const unsigned __int64,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *const &,std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *const &)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\vector(680,5): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>::vector(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>> &)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(677,47): message : see the first reference to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>::vector' in 'std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(1777,44): message : see the first reference to 'std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct' in 'std::_Uninitialized_backout_al<std::allocator<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>>>::_Emplace_back'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory(1831,31): message : see the first reference to 'std::_Uninitialized_backout_al<std::allocator<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>>>::_Emplace_back' in 'std::_Uninitialized_copy'
1>C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(30,1): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>>>' being compiled
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 2:48 PM and took 00.963 seconds ==========
```

I know that unique_ptr can not copy, but is there a way I can use the vector of unique_ptr as value inside a std::map?

- Edit: With the help of comments, now I can pass the compilation, but what I really need is to initialize emptyCacheLine with one std::vector inside already, such as
  `emptyCacheLine.push_back({})`, cause currently it will get runtime error when call `cache["tag"].back()` in `add_to_cache`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that the *only* error message you get? Have you looked at the full and complete build log? On what line are you getting the error? Please [edit] your question to add a comment on that line in the code.

Comment: `cache["row"] = {};` - this creates an empty vector in the map, an empty vector on the right side, copies the second one into the first one, it can't be done, since vector elements are not copyable.

Comment: Regarding maps, if you use an element that doesn't exist yet then it will be automatically created. So you don't actually need `cache["row"] = {}`. It will all work anyway.

Comment: If you need to create that element in advance, you can just write `cache["row"];`.

Comment: Also, I assume you're going to store more than just "rows" in your cache? Otherwise using a map makes no sense. :)

Comment: In my case, I need to initialize the map value first, then append elements into vector's back, something like std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<pure_virtual_class>>>>. I need to init the 
vector of vector first...

Comment: So this isn't really a proper [mre] then?

Comment: Really apologize for not providing a proper case, I will edit my question then

Comment: @273K Is really a vector created on the right side? It seems that the overload of vector's assignment operator that accepts `std::initializer_list` is preferred. Test: https://godbolt.org/z/Tbn1vadzM.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, you're right, I missed the third operator overload. It doesn't matter, it requires copying elements anyway, even if they are of zero amount.

Comment: @273K The difference is that if a vector was created on the right side, no copying would be required then (that vector would be an rvalue). You can easily check it with `cache["row"] = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>{}`, which works fine. Copying is required only because of `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: You should avoid such nested types.... It make the code hard to read with that many anonymous levels and also error prone with text based keys that are repeated across the code (if one key is mispelled, it could be hard to find the source of a bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cache type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>>`, you can initialize the innermost vector with one empty vector in the constructor like this:

```cpp
class Storage {
public:
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>> cache;

  void add_to_cache(std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr) {
    if (cache["row"].empty())
      cache["row"].emplace_back(); // Add an empty vector if none exists
    cache["row"].back().push_back(std::move(ptr));
  }

  void add_new_cacheLine() {
    cache.emplace("row", std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>{});
  }

  Storage() {
    cache["row"].push_back(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>()); // To initialize with one empty vector
  }
};
```

When you call `add_to_cache`, it will check if the innermost vector inside the map is empty. If it is, it adds an empty vector before pushing the `unique_ptr` into the vector. And in the constructor, we initialize `cache["row"]` with one empty vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my cache type is `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>>>`, is it also work for my case?

Comment: Thanks a lot, existing check work for me.